# Sync Azure DevOps Boards between organizations

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

I want to sync the workitems in some Azure DevOps organization into one new, single Azure DevOps organization.

After some searching, I can only find Azure DevOps REST API solution.

In addition, my workitems in different organization, different project have customized columns. Not sure REST API can deal with it?

If there is other better solution, please tell me.